# Should I be worried about lots of script blocks on my page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

When debugging my MVC3 app in Visual Studio using IE9 I see lots of small "script block" entries for my page. My page relies heavily on AJAX, and some actions result in replacing sections of the DOM with partial views coming back from the server.

What I'm seeing is a growing list of these "script block" entries - should I be worried about this? Will this ultimately be a performance problem when the app is live?

Note: the script blocks are quite small bits of code - I've moved most of my significant javascript into their own .js files.

Comment: Do you have unobtrusive JavaScript turned on?

Answer (score 0):

Mm, I thinks it's more of a personal style thing with modern browsers, but if nothing else, trying to contain all the script for a view in one block at the bottom of the page will make for easier debugging and your future self will thank you for it!

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule of thumb I will only have script blocks in pages that need to use the `document.ready` or variables from my viewmodel. Otherwise, I would move all the functions into their own js file.  It helps keep the views cleaner and the browser will load the page faster since it won't block loading the page when it hits as many script tags. Plus, it will make debugging easier since you can go straight to the js file instead of having to find the function within the HTML.